# DROP Database with a WHERE clause - TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to delete any development databases that are older than 15 days by comparing the date column in a specified table.

Is there a way to write a DROP database query with a WHERE clause or do I have to do a dynamic SQL?

Below is my SQL query:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS 
WHERE (SELECT ID FROM master.TableName
        WHERE Date < DATEADD(DAY, -15, GETDATE())
            AND ColumnName1 = 1
            AND ColumnName2 = 0)
```

Comment: if the solution is working for you, please remember to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sp_MSforeachdb` will run a statement on every database.

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb 'IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM [?].dbo.TableName WHERE Date < DATEADD(DAY, -15, GETDATE()) AND ColumnName1 = 1 AND ColumnName2 = 0) DROP DATABASE [?];'
```

Comment: The 'DROP Database' value needs to by dynamic then no? I can't hard code it, like DROP Database TEST_DB

Comment: That's why you can use this statement to iterate over each database, and inside the script you use '?' mark which will be interpretted by the sql engine as your database name. It's dynamic. Only thing you need, is the same table and column to perform where statement on.

Comment: That's why you can use this statement to iterate over each database, and inside the script you use '?' mark which will be interpretted by the sql engine as your database name. It's dynamic. Only thing you need to change, is the name of table and column to perform the 'Where' statement on it.

Comment: The script is trying to drop the master database

Comment: That,s True. The script is iterating over EACH database, even master database. You need to modify IF condition to delete only those databases you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
   IF EXISTS
   (SELECT ID FROM master.TableName
    WHERE Date < DATEADD(DAY, -15, GETDATE())
        AND ColumnName1 = 1
        AND ColumnName2 = 0)
       Drop database ......
```

Comment: Sorry, really noob here, but what do I put after the DROP database? The database name?

Comment: @AznDevil92, please look at my answer, you have a complete statement to run, just table name and where condition is to be changed.

Comment: Yes drop database database_name